# How to use $regex in mongodb aggregation query within $match

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to use the [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/) within [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#stage._S_match), its not returning the matching documents.

```
db.collection('MyCollection', function (err, collection) {
  collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'Code': 'Value_01', 'Field2': { $regex: '/Value_2/g' } } },  
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        CodeNumber: '$Code',
        FieldName2: '$Field2'
      }
    }
  ], function (err, Result_doc) {
    console.log(Result_doc);
  }
});
```

Can anyone tell me where its going wrong or the correct syntax?

---

I even tried with replacing the

```
'Field2': { $regex: /Value_2/g }
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As it says in the `$regex` docs you linked to, the two ways to do this are:

```
Field2: /Value_2/g
```

OR

```
Field2: { $regex: 'Value_2', $options: 'g' }
```

But I also tried your second attempt of `'Field2': { $regex: /Value_2/g }` and that worked as well.

BTW, the `g` regex option doesn't make sense in this context as you just need one match anyway.  Note that it isn't even listed in the `$regex` docs.

Comment: `$options` is not being shown under `$match` query when I enter `$regex:"<value>"`.

Comment: Note: the global option is not supported for MongoDB regex operations ([source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_options:~:text=The%20%24regex%20operator%20does%20not%20support%20the%20global%20search%20modifier%20g.)).

Answer (score 8):

I got it working with the following code:

```
var Value_match = new RegExp('Value_2');

db.collection('MyCollection', function (err, collection) {

  collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { Code: 'Value_01', Field2: { $regex: Value_match } } },  
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        CodeNumber: '$Code',
        FieldName2: '$Field2'
      }
    }
  ], function (err, Result_doc) {
    console.log(Result_doc);
  }
});
```

On pushing the object content to console using `console.dir(Value_match)` it prints out `'/Value_2/'`