# PHP Mongo aggregate match regex

Tags: php, mongodb

Performing a query that simulates a 'like/mysql' searching for teams on the name of the team

Team document structure

```
{
    "_id": 9,
    "name": "azerty",
    "tag": "dsfds",
    "desc": "ggdfgsdfgdfgdf",
    "captain": 8,
    "coach": 8,
    "members": [{
        "date_joined": "2016-03-31 15:22:09",
        "user_id": 8
    }, {
        "date_joined": "2016-03-31 19:22:35",
        "user_id": 9
    }],
    "current_invites": [{
        "invite_id": 21,
        "username": "Nikki",
        "user_id": "9",
        "status": 1,
        "date_invited": "2016-03-31 18:32:40"
    }, {
        "invite_id": 22,
        "username": "Nikki",
        "user_id": "9",
        "status": 2,
        "date_invited": "2016-03-31 18:33:16"
    }]
}
```

PHP Code  =

```
$q = '/.*'.$q.'*./';
$result = $this->coll->aggregate(
           array('$match' => array('name' => $q)),
           array('$project' => array('name' => 1,'members' => array('$size' => '$members'))));
```

Feels like I'm going mad not knowing how to fix this.
Have used regex before after migrating to mongo but not with the combination of agg-match.

Comment: This is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252208/how-to-use-regex-in-mongodb-aggregation-query-within-match

Comment: Found the right post for my situation and using 'new MongoRegex($q)' fixed my issue

Comment: For those stumbling on making mongo regex with php, options should be separated from regex pattern. Something like `['$match' => ['$regex' => '^' . $pattern . '.*', '$options' => 'i']]`. More details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252208/how-to-use-regex-in-mongodb-aggregation-query-within-match

Answer (score 0):

in my case i am finding the aggregated result in which you can not set the where clause so use the aggregated functions like $sort $unwind $orderby and so on i am using the all of the above mention and have the problem with the like stuff to match the string like %str% here my code in which i implement the like using $match with MongoRegex

```
public function getRecords($table,$where = array(),$like_key = false,$like_value = false,$offset = 1,$limit = 10,$order_column = false,$order_type = false, $isAggregate=false,$pipeline=array()){
    $temp = $this->getMongoDb()->where($where);
    if($like_key && $like_value){
        $temp = $temp->like($like_key,$like_value);
        // this like filter is for aggregated result work both on normal get record or by aggregated result
        $pipeline[]=array(
            '$match' => array( $like_key => new MongoRegex( "/$like_value/i" ) )
        );
    }
    if($order_column && $order_type){
        $order_by = array();
        $order_by[$order_column] = $order_type;
        $temp = $temp->order_by($order_by);

        $pipeline[]=array(
            '$sort'=>array($order_column => ($order_type =="desc")? -1 : 1)
        );
    }
```

I got the solution when I read the following aggregation framework [go the aggregation framework](https://derickrethans.nl/aggregation-framework.html)

I hope you will get your solution to resolve your issue.