# Want to join two collections and result should be filter from both collections

Tags: mongodb

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8dae610b209222e10a0ac4"),
    "serial" : "2248",
    "externalId" : "452085",
     "hierarchyPathByIds" : ",5e2eb1662698a2097c71d855,",
    "status" : "ACTIVE",
 }
device_events collection {
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e9d863a235721333eddfb81"),
    "deviceId" : "5e8dae610b209222e10a0ac4",
    "type" : "PACKAGE_TEST",
     "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-04-20T11:04:27.943Z")
}
```

Note -> Have to fetch documents which have same device id in both collections
  if there is no any events with device collection, that would not be come as result. 
 Device Events should filter for last hour and type as well.
 1. Have to fetch all devices which is in device events created date descending order.
 2. hierarchyPathByIds regex pattern match to '.*,5e2eb1662698a2097c71d855,.*'

Device has many device events.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried and what hasn't worked?

Comment: I have used Aggregation(lookup) thing but it also not satisfy my requirement.......  {
    "serial" : "5e8ec16aaa0baa1ed8e5f22e",
    "_id" : "5e8ec16aaa0baa1ed8e5f22e",
    "deviceEvents" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ea295598463e006c7a23633"),
            "deviceId" : "5e8ec16aaa0baa1ed8e5f22e",
            "type" : "PACKAGE_TEST",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-04-24T07:29:29.733Z")
        }] }

Comment: [menna uththare](https://gist.github.com/dj-nitehawk/4f9a9bc567ddbc934e0811f802266628)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you store `deviceId` as `String` in device collection, you have to convert

**Option 1**
convert _id `ObjectId` to `String` of **device** collection

```
db.device.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": {
                "$toString": "$_id"
            },
            serial: 1,
            externalId: 1,
            status: 1

        }
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'device_events',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'deviceId',
            as: 'join'
        }
    }
])
```

**Option 2** convert deviceId `String` to `ObjectId` of **device_events** collection

```
db.device_events.aggerate([
    {
        $project: {
            "deviceObjId": {
                "$toObjectId": "$deviceId"
            },
            _id: 0,
            type: 1
        }
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'device',
            localField: 'deviceObjId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'join'
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, So I want to emit empty array join as well.     {
    "serial" : "2259",
    "_id" : "5e8f5028414a60740b9cee92",
    "join" : []
}    , How should I do that?

Comment: just use {$unwind: "$join","preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true} after the lookup

Comment: Yeah that also fine. And need to match regex pattern with device collection field, How should I do that?

Comment: When you ask a question, please clearly mention everything, most of the developers delete thire codes after responding.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252208/how-to-use-regex-in-mongodb-aggregation-query-within-match

Comment: db.getCollection('devices').aggregate([
{
    "$project": {
      "_id": {
        "$toString": "$_id"
      },
      "hierarchyPathByIds" :{$regex: ".*,5e2eb1662698a2097c71d855,.*,", $options: 'g'}
    }
}}]  It was not worked for me.

Comment: Please explain clearly

Comment: I have modify the my question now. Can You please read it and give me solution

Comment: {$match: {
        hierarchyPathByIds: {
            $regex: ",5e2eb1662698a2097c71d855,"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": {
            "$toString": "$_id"
        },
        serial: 1,
        externalId: 1,
        status: 1,
        hierarchyPathByIds: 1

    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'device_events',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'deviceId',
        as: 'join'
    }
},{
    $unwind: {
        path: '$join',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
},{
    $sort: {
        "join.createdAt": 1
    }
}

Comment: This question is closed. Please create a new question.